# post returns json data with slashes

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm authenticating users on my app with a username and password with angular 2 and ionic.
When i use the `subscribe` method i get the data returned from the server like this

```
{"_body":"[{\"FullName\”:\”user\”,\”PhoneNo\”:\”0001\”}]”,”status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"content-type":["text/html"]},"type":2,"url":"http://webserver.com/login.php"}
```

with slash in the data.

when i use `rxjx` method it failed to get any response from the server and it reads `error sending`
How do i fix my script so i get the data return like this

```
[{"FullName”:”user”,”PhoneNo”:”0001”}]
```

just like the normal json

Below is my script which i use to post to the server

```
this.http.post("http://webserver.com/login.php",{'username':this.username,'password':this.password}).subscribe(data=>{
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
},error=>{
  console.log("error sending")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When getting the response from the server, you need to extract the body of that response. You can do that by adding this line of code `.map(res => res.json())` like this:

```
let data = { 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password };

this.http.post("http://webserver.com/login.php", data)
    .map(res => res.json()) // <---- Here!
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error sending")
        });
```